# Screen Dimmer in Ubuntu than in Windows - Haswell NEC Lavie

Tags: 13.10, screen, brightness

I just bought a new laptop, on which I immediately installed Ubuntu 13.10.

Pretty much everything worked out of the box, except the screen brightness. The maximum brightness in Ubuntu is much lower than it was with the preinstalled Windows 8. Brightness controls work, but they go from backlight being totally off to something like 50-60% of Windows brightness.

I've tried changing grub settings to acpi_vendor=legacy as well as vendor. I've also tried various settings for the osi string.

Any ideas how to diagnose and fix this? I think I'm the first person to ever install linux on this particular laptop. It's an NEC Lavie LZ750, imported from Japan. It's an i7-4500U using intel graphics.

Any help would really be appreciated. I love this laptop and can't really consider switching back to windows, but the screen is really dim.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

Then you can set the backlights brightness percentage from terminal

```
xbacklight -set 10
```

Also you may want to take a look at `dconf-editor`.  If its not installed, just do:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Once installed, from the left pane, navigate to org --> gnome --> settings-daemon --> plugins --> power.  See image below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to write this out. I'd tried xbacklight before, and I already have it at 100. The Fn keys actually work to control the brightness, it's just that the maximum is much dimmer than it was in windows.

I tried dconf per your suggestion but it appears that that only affects the screen when idle. Even so, I tried messing with the settings and rebooting, but nothing changed.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Brightness Controller](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/brightness-controller/).